# How do I efficiently load multiple CDNJS/CloudFlare assets in parallel?

Tags: javascript, cloudflare

I am using a load of CDNJS Javascript assets, but noticing that they are not loading in parallel. Could I improve the responsiveness with differing code?

I have seen articles about domain sharding, but couldn't find alternative CDNJS domains, and this may not be the actual solution either.

Example of CDNJS assets requested in Chrome Devtools:

[image]

Comment: Are you loading the CDNJS files over HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: I support https, and infer the protocol based on the protocol of the main request (https is not enforced in page access)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloudflare (and by extension CDNJS) support HTTP/2, but only over HTTPS connections. HTTP/2 brings many performance improvements when loading a lot of small assets. For example, when HTTP/2 is used, only one connection is made to each domain and all requests are multiplexed, so in theory any amount of separate assets from the same domain should load just as fast as a single concatenated asset. This also eliminates the need for domain sharding.

To take advantage of the performance improvements of HTTP/2, make sure you always load the CDNJS assets over HTTPS, regardless of whether your own page is being served via HTTP or HTTPS.

Comment: Excellent, very helpful information which appears to solve it, much appreciated